# Canvas javascript clear path

Tags: html5-canvas

I am testing out a little Canvas programming and I have a question about how to clear previous paths when drawing a new one.

Example:
Paint a filled circle with no stroke and a stroked line.
I have the following code:

```
graphicContext.save();
graphicContext.beginPath();
graphicContext.arc(95,50,40,0,2*Math.PI);
graphicContext.fillStyle="rgb(50, 200, 200)";
graphicContext.fill();
graphicContext.restore();

graphicContext.save();
graphicContext.moveTo(0,0);
graphicContext.lineTo(200,100);
graphicContext.stroke();
graphicContext.restore();
```

However, both the circle and the line are stroked. How can I stroke the line without also stroking the circle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, there is no need to use [**`save`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/save) and [**`restore`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/restore) method.

Second, use [**`beginPath`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/beginPath) method before drawing the line, as you are creating a new path. `beginPath` will reset / clear the previous path ...

```js
var graphicContext = document.querySelector('#canvas').getContext('2d')

// circle
graphicContext.beginPath();
graphicContext.arc(95,50,40,0,2*Math.PI);
graphicContext.fillStyle="rgb(50, 200, 200)";
graphicContext.fill();

// line
graphicContext.beginPath();
graphicContext.moveTo(0,0);
graphicContext.lineTo(200,100);
graphicContext.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```